# Textarea with defaultValue not updating

Tags: reactjs

Hey I've got a problem with changing the content of a textarea.

This is my textarea

```
<textarea
  className="fixedTextArea"
  defaultValue={this.props.predefValueSets[this.props.selection].values}
  onChange={(event) => this.changeHandle(event)}
/>
```

Now when `this.props.selection` changes I want to have the content of the textarea to change as well.
I can't use `value` instead of `defaultValue`, because my textarea has to be editable.

When I look in the browser and inspect my textarea I see, how the content changes, but they aren't reflected.

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS component textarea not updating on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775004/reactjs-component-textarea-not-updating-on-state-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that fits best for me atm is to use `<div>` instead of  `<textarea>`.

I am using:

```
<div
  className="fixedTextArea"
  contentEditable
  suppressContentEditableWarning>
  {this.props.predefValueSets[this.props.selection].values}
</div>
```

This took an easy way to manage `onChange(...)` (cause a `<div>` doesn't fire onChange-Events), but that isn't important in my specific case.

Answer (score -1):

use `ref`

```
<textarea
  className="fixedTextArea"
  ref="fixedTextArea"
  defaultValue={this.props.predefValueSets[this.props.selection].values}
  onChange={(event) => this.changeHandle(event)}
/>
```

everytime the value changes, update the text area.

```
changeHandle(value){
  this.refs.fixedTextArea.value = value
}
```

Comment: You mean to change the textarea value, whenever `this.props.selection` changes, right? Doing it this way just doesn't feel like the "react-way". Updating components directly shouldn't be our responsibility.

Comment: yes, but the other way is to bind the value on state, and update the state each time the `onChange` occurs, 
see here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Yes, you're right. Adding it directly to the state would be a way.

Comment: yeah, but sometimes the changes is too fast, so react will do the render each time a character is inserted or removed from the text area. 
by handling the changes manually, you could do some `debounce` and handles the state change only when user stop typing.